# Change position of a TreeView to the Panel from ActivityBar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm fully able to move my TreeView from the SideBar to the bottom panel (Problems, output, terminal...).

However, I'm uncertain how I would go about making my TreeView appear in the bottom panel by default. The documentation doesn't state anything about the bottom panel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the `panel` as an option for the `viewContainer` as in:

```
"contributes": {
    "viewsContainers": {
        "panel" : [           // instead of activityBar here
            {
                "id": "your virewContainer id",
                "title": "your title",
                "icon": "$(....)"
            }
                
        ]
    }
}
```

Found by using intellisense.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks Mark